# Problems with materials while exporting and importing a project into another project in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

[image: Grass before importing and after importing]I have a project in Unity, and it needed some grass swing. So I downloaded a free project from Git Hub. Everything was fine but when I **exported and imported** it into my project, **all the materials broke. They where pink and some materials didn't render (They where invisible).**

When I searched the internet why this happens and it was **problems with shaders**.

But how if I exported it and imported it back again. Even I copied the code and pasted it again.

Can someone help me?

Github for the project with grass: https://github.com/daniel-ilett/shaders-6grass

and the tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHDmqfdVkak

Answer (score 0):

If You are using URP,HDRP in your project you have to convert the imported materials

**If you are using HDRP** Go To Edit>Rendering>Materials> Then Select Convert All Built in Materials to HDRP

**If you are using URP**  You have to select the materials that are purple and Go To Edit>Rendering>Materials> Then Select Convert Selected Built in Materials to URP

Comment: It didn't work. Instead it gave me a warning saying:

GeometryGrass material was not upgraded. There's no upgrader to convert Custom/GeometryGrass shader to selected pipeline
UnityEditor.Rendering.Universal.UniversalRenderPipelineMaterialUpgrader:UpgradeSelectedMaterialsMenuItem () (at Library/PackageCache/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.1.11/Editor/UniversalRenderPipelineMaterialUpgrader.cs:61)

Comment: As I can see from the question materials in the original source are fine. So if versions of Unity in the source and target projects are the same then it is not shader conversion problem

Comment: The problem is with the shader after importing the shader click on it on the inspector you will be seeing this error couldn't open include file  'packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal/shaderlibrary/core.hlsl' Are you using HDRP

Comment: No, I'm using URP

Comment: can you include a screenshot of your material in the inspector

Comment: I included the screenshots

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by upgrading the shaders (only the required ones)